# Error being thrown when observable is inside another observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

The control goes to the error block when the inner observable completed execution.

My Component Service Layer - The control goes to the error block.

```
   this.ApplicationService.getPageData(id).subscribe((DataObj)=>{
      console.log(DataObj);
   },
   (error)=>{
      console.log('Failed to get data.'); <-- The control comes here
   })
```

In my Application Service Layer -

```
    return this.dbService.queryData(req).pipe(mergeMap((r)=>{
        if(r!=null) {
           let key : string = r.other_id;
           return dbService.queryOtherSource(key).pipe(map((r1)=> {
                    if(r1) {
                        obj = do some data processing
                        return of(obj); <-- Control comes here.
                    }
                },
                (err)=> {
                    throw err;
                }));
            }            
        },
        (error)=>{
            throw error;
        }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MergeMap and Map are not accepting error handling. You are using the mergeMap argument `resultSelector` that is throwing the error you see.

There is a specific operator to process them. Throw errors when you need to (with a throw new Error or a `throwError()` from rxjs). If you need to handle it at a specific spot in the Observable chain, use the operator `catchError()` in the pipe.

See this stackblitz for a working demonstration of error handling based on your code :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h88bjo

There is also no point of rethrowing an error without adding any information. From the moment the error is thrown, it will propagate to the top level if not catched.